# Creating formulas for the Moodle CMS question bank

Tags: output-formatting

**Edit** *I have made some progress on this problem, which is given below the question.*

I use the Moodle course management system for much of my teaching, and the CMS comes with a tool for creating on-line quizzes.  A quiz question can take the form of a "calculated question type" which allows for variables to be used in the question and the answer will be calculated based on a formula involving those variables.

The problem is, the calculated question type has a [very limited set of functions](https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/Calculated_question_type) that can be used to create formulas .  An example question might be?

> Calculate the mean of {a}, {b}, and {c}.

Where the variables are indicated by alphanumeric symboles within curly braces.  Since there is no `mean()` or `average()` function, I am forced to enter the following in the answer block:

> ({a}+{b}+{c})/3

For a trivial problem such as this one, I can manage the answer block; however, if I were to ask for something like the `StandardDeviation`, the equation quickly becomes burdensome.

**I'd like to use *Mathematica* to create the appropriate form of the function to be put into the answer block.**

Ideally, I'd like a `MoodleForm[expr]` that will take a valid *Mathematica* expression and convert it into a valid Moodle answer expression (or state that it doesn't know how to make the conversion:

```
MoodleForm[a+b+c] -> {a} + {b} + {c}
MoodleForm[Mean[{a,b,c}] -> ({a} + {b} + {c})/3
MoodleForm[ListPlot[{a,b,c}] -> "I can't do that, BoB"
```

Sadly, I'm stuck at the very beginning.  If I make the assumption that `a`, `b` and `c` are all undefined in the current *Mathematica* context, I thought I could do something like this to separate out Symbols that are in the "System`" context.

```
expr1 = a + b + c;
expr1 /. x_Symbol /; Context[x] == "Global`" :> {x}
```

Clearly, I need to be thinking about this problem in a different way, and I welcome any suggestions on how to proceed.

---

### Progress

My 'inspiration' for this approach is based on the results of `TreeForm[Mean[{a,b,c}]]`

[image]

I thought that if I could create lists with a function as the first element and the arguments as the remaining elements, I might be able to get the desired formatting.  Prepare for some ugly code:

```
Clear[mdSimplifier];
mdSimplifier[expr_] := Module[{out},
  (* Assume we always deal with Reals, sorry Mathematicians*)
  out = expr /. {Conjugate[x_] :> x};
  N@out
  ]
Clear[mdLeveler];
mdLeveler[expr_] := Module[{},
  If[Depth[#] == 1, #, Level[#, {1}, Heads -> True]] &@expr
  ]
Clear[mdOperate];
mdOperate[expr_List] := Module[{out, hd, rst},
  out = N /@ expr;
  (* If the first element of expr is a Symbol and none of the rest \
are lists *)
  If[And @@ Flatten[{
      Head@First@expr == Symbol,
      (List =!= #) & /@ (Rest@expr)}],
   hd = First@expr;
   rst = Rest@expr;
   Switch[hd,
    Times, ToString[hd @@ rst],
    Power, 
    "pow(" <> ToString[rst[[1]]] <> "," <> ToString[N@rst[[2]]] <> 
     ")"],
   expr]
  ]
Clear[mdPrettyPrint];
mdPrettyPrint[expr_String] := Module[{out},
  out = StringReplace[expr,
    "md" ~~ x : DigitCharacter :> "{md" ~~ x ~~ "}"
    ]
  ]
```

I've created several functions to help compartmentalize the problem.  Here is how I implement the solution for `expr = StandardDeviation[{md1,md2,md3}]`

```
mdSimplifier[expr] (* Gets rid of fractions and makes an assumption of Real values *)
mdLeveler[%] (* Returns a Function/arguments list if possible *)
out = mdLeveler /@ % (* See Point 1 below *)
out[[3]] = mdOperate[out[[3]]] (* See Point 2 below *)
mdPrettyPrint@mdOperate[out]
```

> "0.408248 pow({md1} (2. {md1} - 1. {md2} - 1. {md3}) + {md2} (-1. \
>   {md1} + 2. {md2} - 1. {md3}) + {md3} (-1. {md1} - 1. {md2} + 2. \
>   {md3}),0.5)"

With a little more tweaking, this string generates the desired output when I use it in the Moodle CMS, which for reference is:

> 0.408248 * pow({md1} * (2. * {md1} - {md2} -  {md3}) + {md2} * (- {md1} + 2. * {md2} -  {md3}) + {md3} * (- {md1} -  {md2} + 2. * {md3}),0.5)

The issues now are:

- Point 1 - How do I apply `mdLeveler` so that it will dig into the expression so that I don't have to apply it multiple times manually?
- Point 2 - `mdOperate` suffers from the same problem as does `mdLeveler`.
- Point 3 - The Moodle CMS wants explicit multiplication symbols, and I don't know if it is possible to add them automatically.

Comment: One quick thought: the output should be a `String` so you can copy it into a text field of the CMS. Also: maybe it's easier if you choose your variable names according to some pattern, e.g., `moodle[a]`, `moodle[b]`, etc.

Comment: @Jens, the pattern-containing variable name is an excellent idea that I hadn't thought of.  Thanks.

Comment: @bobthechemist is it possible to have CDFs in moodle and get info passed back and forth?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I've been able to embed CDFs in Moodle without too much difficulty (HTML scrubbing sometimes gets in the way), but I've not been able to get more sophisticated integration.  I started looking in to whether or not Enterprise CDF might allow for it, but our school decided to stop paying for the Mathematica license. sigh.

Comment: @bobthechemist thanks. At the very least you would need enterprise CDFs I would think ...although you can import from HTML addresses in free CDF I think (would would allow REST based communication).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the simplest method is `CForm` with small string postprocessing

```
moodleForm[expr_] := StringReplace[#, {"power" -> "pow", 
       "md(" ~~ Shortest@x__ ~~ ")" :> "{" ~~ x ~~ "}"}] &@
    ToLowerCase@ToString[#, CForm] &@Simplify[expr, Assumptions -> _md ∈ Reals]

StandardDeviation[{md[a], md[b], md[c]}] // moodleForm

(*sqrt(pow({a},2) + pow({b},2) - {b}*{c} + pow({c},2) - {a}*({b} + {c}))/sqrt(3)*)
```

Comment: It never occurred to me that Moodle was using a c-type format.  This solution works brilliantly.